# tinymce widget usage in django template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-tinymce

I created a model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    body = models.TextField()
```

and created **forms.py** as

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model  = Post
        fields = ('title', 'body',)
```

I have added tinymce and it works in admin but doesn't render it in template. I tried to override the form through a variant of forms.py as

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    title = forms.TextField(widget=TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 100, 'rows': 10})

    class Meta:
        model  = Post
        fields = ('title', 'body',)
```

but it doesn't work . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) Add the Media class to your form:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'body',)

    class Media:
        js = ('/site_media/static/tiny_mce/tinymce.min.js',)
```

2.) Add the following to the html file which should display the editor:

```
{{ form.media }}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% url "tinymce-js" "tinymce" %}"></script>
```

3.) Add the following url entry to your project urls.py:

```
url(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
```

4.) In your model declare your tinymce editor fields as TextFields. In your case if you only want to display the editor for your body field, write your model in the following way:

```
class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField()
    body = models.TextField()
```

Comment: what should i do if i would like to display the tinymce editor for only body and not the title. I am not sure how to change the PostForm.

Comment: declare your body field as a TextField and the title as a CharField.